# Continues Integration through email approval in TFS release definition

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 14.102.25423.0

As part of our company's continues integration deployment,
I want to implement the following:
I have created a release definition with two environments configured under it (QA & Production).

I want to receive an email when all the tasks in the QA environment are completed **successfully**.
In that email there should be a button that once pressed, the Production tasks will start.

I would love to hear any ideas how do I implement this.
All I've found so far are build alerts and not release alerts.

Thanks,
Much appreciated.

Comment: This may be a starting point: TFS Releases REST API https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/approvals

Answer (score 2):

Add a requirement for an approval prior to production deployment and ensure that the "Send Email Notification" option is enabled. You'll get an email with a link to provide the approval, which will trigger the production release.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty simply in TFS.

1. In your release process, select **Edit**
   [image: edit]
2. Select **Triggers**
   [image: triggers]
3. Find your Production environment in the Environment triggers section and select the **Edit** pencil. 
   [image: environmental variables]
4. Select **Approvals**
5. You can then set Pre-deployment and Post-Deployment approvers.
6. In the Options section, select the **Send an email notification to the approver** option
   [image: set email, who, when and where]

This will send an email on pre-approval if that is what you selected.

Comment: how to do this in the 'new editor'  I can't find these options without using 'old editor'

Comment: @MPavlak which 'new editor' version exactly? I looked in Visual Studio Team Services (which is the newest thing out there) and it's almost identical to this. If it's TFS 2017, then I can't say much about that, since I don't have access to that on-prem version.

Comment: VSTS has a 'new editor' that will display a banner to try out.  It visualizes the release pipeline differently among other things.

Comment: @MPavlak Interesting. I'll have to try it out! :)