# VSTS Release Approval Emails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using the 'Old Editor', there is a way to configure release environment to send emails to approvers via Release Definition > Triggers > Configure Environment as seen in this screen shot.  ([see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229071/continues-integration-through-email-approval-in-tfs-release-definition))

[image]

Is there a way to do this using the 'New Editor'?  Seems like the options for email and blocking the creating user from approving are missing from this workflow.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that, for example, if you stick yourself in the list of approvers, you don't get an email?

Comment: correct. i do not get an email.  none of the approvers are receiving emails

Answer (score 2):

You can set Approval email notification in the page https://account.visualstudio.com/_notifications (by clicking profile -> Notification settings).

In the notications package, you can add a new subscription for **An approval for a deployment is pending**, and then specify the email address(es) and filter conditions.

> with the integrated notification settings experience, we are moving
>   the control on notifications from the sender to the receiver. By
>   default, we'll always raise notification events whenever approvals are
>   pending and based on receiver's preferences around whether he wants to
>   be notified by email or not.

More details, you can refer:

[Personalize what notifications you receive for releases](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/27/personalize-what-notifications-you-receive-for-releases/)

[New Release Editor does not expose option to Send email to approver](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/81053/new-release-editor-does-not-expose-option-to-send.html)

Example: 
In notification page, add a new subscription  An approval for a deployment is pending, the detail settings as below:

[image]

Just add the email address(es) who need to receive this kind of email, for multiple email addresses, separate with comma (`,`).

Comment: I went to this tab and under Release group, there was already an item for "Deployment approval pending; notifies you when an approval for a deployment is pending on you - Any Project" and it is On.  However, no emails are being sent.

Comment: Please add new notification and you can specify the email address and filters. For the Deployment approval pending is inherent notification and you can't change anything. So the better way is creating a new notification for release, such as **An approval for a deployment is pending**.

Comment: I added this notification, but was not able to target it to only the people that would be able to approve.  The options are Specific users (Assigned To, & Environment Owner), All Team, Team Preferences, Team Email Address.  The Deployment approval pending has a filter for 'Data.SendApprovalMail' = 1, but this is not an option for the new notification.  None of the available filters are seemingly useful.

Comment: You just need to specify the email address (I added an example in the end of my answer), and then it can work well.

Comment: MPavlak, If you specify yourself as an approver, does the built-in subscription work for you? Secondly your approver seems to be a group identity, thus you should check group's subscriptions instead of your personal subscriptions.

Comment: Yes, if you want yourself receive the email notification, you just need to specify your email address here. But the email address(es) here is not auto related with pre-deployment approver(s). Such as I only specified myself as the pre-deployment approver, but I can set not only myself receive the email notification (I can add my email address and user2's email address to receive the emails).